# How to obtain constexpr `.size()` of a non-static std::array member

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, stdarray

Given that `std::array<T,N>::size` is constexpr, in the snippet below

- Why does it matter that `Foo1::u` is not a `static` member? The type is known at compile time and so is its `size()`.
- What's wrong with `Foo2::bigger()`?

Listing:

```
// x86-64 gcc 10.1
// -O3 --std=c++20 -pedantic -Wall -Werror

#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

union MyUnion {
    std::array<uint8_t,32> bytes;
    std::array<uint32_t,8> words;
};

struct Foo1 {
    MyUnion u;
    static constexpr size_t length {u.bytes.size()};
        //invalid use of non-static data member 'Foo1::u'
};

struct Foo2 {
    MyUnion u;
    size_t x;
    consteval int8_t length() const { return u.bytes.size(); };
    bool bigger() const { return x > length(); }
        //'this' is not a constant expression
};
```

I would like to keep std::array length in `MyUnion` declaration and not resort to

```
constexpr size_t LEN {32};
union MyUnion {
    std::array<uint8_t,LEN> bytes;
    std::array<uint32_t,LEN/4> words;
};
```

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. The two compilation errors have different reasons.

Comment: By the way, you cannot use `words` if you initialized `bytes` since they don't have a common initial sequence

Comment: imagine a static function breaking because you changed a non-static class member.   That's not good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These situations are a bit different.

In the first one:

```cpp
    static constexpr size_t length {u.bytes.size()};
        //invalid use of non-static data member 'Foo1::u'
```

You're trying to access a non-static data member without an object. That's just not a thing you can do. There needs to be *some* `Foo1` associated with this expression. In the context of a non-static member function, it'd implicitly be `this->u`, but there still needs to be some object there. There's only one exception: you're allowed to write `sizeof(Foo1::u)`.

---

In the second one:

```cpp
    consteval int8_t length() const { return u.bytes.size(); };
```

Here, the `this` pointer is not itself a constant expression (we don't know what it points to), so accessing anything through it fails. This is part of a broader case of constant expressions using unknown references in a way that doesn't really affect the constant-ness of the expression (see my blog post on the [constexpr array size problem](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/)). I recently wrote a paper [on this topic](https://wg21.link/p2280) which was focused primarily on references, but `this` is a narrow extension on top of that.

Either way, for now this can't work either, because everything has to be a constant. So you'll have to resort to something along the lines of what you suggest: expose the constant you want separately.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend "resorting to" a variable to define the size in the first place:

```
union MyUnion {
    static constexpr std::size_t size = 32;

    using byte = std::uint8_t;
    using word = std::uint32_t;
    
    std::array<byte, size> bytes;
    std::array<word, size / sizeof(word)> words;
};

struct Foo1 {
    using Union = MyUnion;
    Union u;
    static constexpr std::size_t length = Union::size;
};
```

> Why does it matter that Foo1::u is not a static member?

Non-static members can be accessed only within member functions.

---

I recommend using `std::variant` instead of `union`. It's much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get it from type

```
// direct
consteval static auto length() { return std::tuple_size<decltype(MyUnion::bytes)>::value; }
// with indirection
consteval static auto length() { return std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<decltype(u.bytes)>>::value; }
```

---

Or you can do it by create new instance.

```
// direct
consteval static auto length() { return MyUnion{.bytes={}}.bytes.size(); }
// just the member + indirection
consteval static auto length() { return decltype(u.bytes){}.size(); }
```

---

For the errors you got in your code

> invalid use of non-static data member 'Foo1::u'

means you cannot use non-static data member `u` without instance (e.g. inside `static` member function).

> 'this' is not a constant expression*

means you cannot call `this.length()` (simply because it's `consteval` but `this` is not here)

Why? because it's what the standard say, otherwise there is no reason to use `constexpr` specifier at all because compiler can infer it, isn't it?

---

Related question:

- [Why is constexpr not automatic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660036/why-is-constexpr-not-automatic)
- [Why isn't std::array::size static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936507/why-isnt-stdarraysize-static)

Comment: of course you can also get the size from `decltype(u.bytes)` with some template if you do sure it's `std::array`, see also [Why isn't std::array::size static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936507/why-isnt-stdarraysize-static)